# Why can I no longer deserialize this data?

Tags: c#, .net, json, winforms, serialization

I am using the following code to serialize some data and save it to file:

```
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer((typeof(Item)));

        Item item = ((Item)list.SelectedItems[0].Tag);
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, item);

        var filepath = Program.appDataPath + list.SelectedItems[0].Group.Name + ".group";

        stream.Position = 0;

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            stream.WriteTo(fileStream);
        }
```

And later on, I'm trying to read back that data from file and insert it into ListView:

```
    private void OpenFiles()
    {
        // DEBUG ONLY:
        // Read into memorystream and filestream.
        Console.WriteLine("Attempeting to open note.");

        bool canLoad = false;
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Program.appDataPath))
        {
            if (file.EndsWith(".group"))
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
                    new DataContractJsonSerializer(
                        typeof(
                        List<Item>
                        )
                        );
                using (FileStream fileStream =
                    new FileStream(
                        file,
                        FileMode.Open)
                        )
                {
                    fileStream.CopyTo(stream);
                }

                stream.Position = 0;
                //List<Withdrawal> tempWithList = new List<Withdrawal>();
                foreach (Item item in (List<Item>)serializer.ReadObject(stream))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Title + " " + item.Group.Name);
                    Item.Items.Add(item);
                }

                //Console.WriteLine("Got file \{file}");

                //if (file.EndsWith(".group"))
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine("File is a group.");

                //    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                //    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Item>));

                //    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
                //    {
                //        fileStream.CopyTo(stream);
                //    }

                //    Console.WriteLine("Got stream");

                //    stream.Position = 0;

                //    try
                //    {
                //        Item.Items = (List<Item>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                //        Console.WriteLine("WTF?");
                //    }
                //    catch(Exception exception)
                //    {
                //        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                //    }

                //    Console.WriteLine(Item.Items.Count);

                //    canLoad = true;
                //}
                //else Console.WriteLine("File is not a group.");
            }

            if (canLoad)
            {
                //list.Items.Clear();


                foreach (Item item in Item.Items)
                {
                    ListViewGroup group = new ListViewGroup(item.Group.Name);
                    list.Groups.Add(group);
                    list.Items.Add(
                        new ListViewItem(
                            item.Title,
                            group)
                            );

                    Console.WriteLine(item.Title + " " + item.Group.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, the above **exact** code works in an older program (few months old), but it's not working in a new program. I have no idea why. I have set breakpoints EVERYWHERE and it has proven to be kind of pointless in this case.

One thing I did learn from setting a breakpoint is that even though the stream contains the data expected, the very next second, when it gets added to list, it is NULL. There is nothing in the list. I've run out of ideas, and Google wasn't of much help.

Group.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Notes
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Group
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Item.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Notes
{
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class Item : Note
    {
        [DataMember]
        public static List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

        [DataContract]
        public enum ItemType
        {
            Group,
            Note
        }

        [DataMember]
        public ItemType Type { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Index { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Notes
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Note
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Group Group;

    [DataContract]
    public enum NoteImportance
    {
        Important,
        Neutral,
        NotImportant
    }

    [DataMember]
    public NoteImportance Importance { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Protected { get; set; }
}
}
```

How can I deserialize these objects/read from file and get them into a List or ListView? I've already done this, but for some reason it's not working anymore.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the class structure has changed. It's different between serialization and de-serialization.

Comment: @Khan I'm not quite sure I understand. So you mean my class structure has changed or the way we deserialise data has changed?

Comment: I don't know. Either change could cause problems. It's likely that your class structure has changed.

Comment: You're serializer is for type `DataContractJsonSerializer((typeof(Item)))` but your deserializer is for type `new DataContractJsonSerializer(
                        typeof(
                        List<Item>
                        )
                        )`.  Those don't match.  One is `typeof(Item)`, the other is `typeof(List<Item>)`.

Comment: Looks like each `.group` file has a single `Item`, so `DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Item))` is likely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `.group` file, you serialize a single `Item`:

```
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Item));

    // And later
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, item);
```

But when you deserialize the contents of a `.group` file, you try to deserialize a `List<Item>`:

```
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Item>));

    // And later
    foreach (Item item in (List<Item>)serializer.ReadObject(stream))
    {
        Item.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Those types don't match.  But in order to deserialize the data you previously serialized, they need to match - or at least, the deserialized type cannot be a collection if the serialized type was, because collections are serialized as JSON arrays while other classes are serialized as JSON objects (name/value pairs).

Since it looks like each `.group` file has a single item, and there are many `.group` files in the directory you are scanning, you probably just want to do

```
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Item));

    // And later
    var item = (Item)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    if (item != null)
        Item.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. This works. Very different from what I had. I didn't realise until just now that there was 1 change that was made, which was ` : Note` in the Item class. I am guessing that's why the same deserialization code no longer works.